# Refresh inherited component upon navigate

Tags: angular

Hi can you guys help me i'm kind of new to Angular hoping you could shed some light :) . So I have a main component which consist of 2 inherited sub components.

Sub comp 1 is a list which on clicking will trigger a router.navigate to the main component.

Sub comp 2 is a table with data.

All is working as expected on initial load. However refreshing the main component would not trigger a refresh on its 2 sub component. Sub comp 1 is invoking the refresh with something like this :

```
this.router.navigate(['/main'], { queryParams: { templateid: matchId, userid: 111} });
```

My main component template is like this :

```
<div>
     <comp-1></comp-1>
     <comp-2><comp-2>
</div>
```

and its codebehind is just a simple code which accepts query params:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    userid: number = 0;
    templateid: number = 0;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.route
            .queryParams
            .subscribe(params => {

            if (typeof params['userid'] != 'undefined' || typeof params['templateid'] != 'undefined') {

                this.userid = params['userid'];
                this.templateid = params['templateid'];
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "refreshing the main component". How do you refresh it. Also as Sub comp 1 is inside the main component, which means your current route is main component. So why do you navigate to main component in Sub Comp 1 click?

Comment: I realized indeed that it doesnt make sense to refresh main page  with its child, I resolved this by adding 2 components instead and making on of them @ViewChild of the other to refresh the data. closing this one out. THanks

Answer (score 0):

I realized indeed that it doesnt make sense to refresh main page with its child, I resolved this by adding 2 components instead and making on of them @ViewChild of the other to refresh the data. closing this one out. THanks